# Repeater -button click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater, linkbutton

I have an Add button outside the Repeater control.When ADD IS Clicked a new row is inserted into database and databinded to repeater.
On click of ADD button i want a linkbutton to be showed in the new row of repeater.

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
 DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("lnksave"), LinkButton).Visible = True
```

This code i can not place in my ADD button's click event.what changes should i make to show the linkbutton in newly created row.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?  StackOverflow isn't a magic code factory, you need to show you've put in some effort in solving your own problem, and highlight for us the specific issue you're having with that solution.  The article on [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a question is generally a good guide to start with.

Comment: Adrian, this is what i tried.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would set  LinkButton's property `Visible="false"` in the markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ...
... ... ...
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnksave" runat="server" Visible="false">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

In the code behind declare a flag at page level:

```
Dim btnClicked As Boolean = False
```

In Add button's event method set the flag to true. then data bind the repeater:

```
Protected Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    btnClicked = True
    BindRepeater() 'your method to data bind repeater
End Sub
```

In the repeater's item databound event method check the flag and set the link button's visible property accordingly:

```
Protected Sub Repeater1_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles Repeater1.ItemDataBound
    If (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem) Then
        Dim lnksave As LinkButton = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("lnksave"), LinkButton)
        lnksave.Visible = btnClicked 
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.When i click add i can show save link button in newly created row [BUT it is showing to all other rows].I want it to be in newly created row only